# undefined method `user_signed_in?' - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

SOLVED: Im was using the method 'clear_helpers' in ApplicationController, so it was blocking Devise to load his helpers.

Hello,

When I run my application in the first time on 'development' mode, I get this error, when I reload the error desapear. When I run on 'production' the error still, because production loads application only one time (?), so what is happening? Someone can help?

Error:

```
undefined method `user_signed_in?' for #<#<Class:0x10312ddc0>:0x103127100>

Extracted source (around line #16):

13: 
14:             #top
15:                 = link_to '', root_path, :id => 'logo'
16:                 - if user_signed_in?
17:                     #session
18:                         %p= raw "Olá <b>#{current_user.email}</b>"          
19:                         #myaccount.button{:onclick => "javascript: document.location.href = '#{edit_user_registration_path}'"}
```

Im using Devise with following setup:

Rails: 3.1, Devise: 1.3.4

My model:

```
class User::Account < ActiveRecord::Base  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :recoverable,
         :rememberable, :registerable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable
end
```

Routes:

```
Foco::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :class_name => 'User::Account'

  root :to => 'main/cockpit#index', :constraints => lambda {|r| r.env["warden"].authenticate? }

  devise_scope :user do
    root :to => "devise/registrations#new"
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
class Main::CockpitController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the if user_signed_in? call does the current_user.email display after you have logged in?

Comment: No, same error for 'current_user' (undefined) =/

Comment: And you did authenticate with the application?

Comment: Yes, I can only access this controller authenticated, how you can see in routes. I think the problem is something like the layout is being loaded before authentication method, because if I can reload Ruby code, it run.

Comment: Can you create an answer with your solution in it and accept it? That way anyone else having a similar problem will benefit from your pain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method 'clear_helpers' in ApplicationController was blocking Devise to load his helpers.

So I removed this method and app works.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because I was doing some weird stuff with my devise routes. Making them normal solved it for me.

Comment: Absolutely useless answer. 'Weird' stuff with your devise routes? Is 'weird' technical jargon for I don't know the real answer to this question...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the functions you are trying to call are not defined. When you run rails g devise User you get the functions that you are trying to use, however if you used something nonstandard you need to use the singular version of that. SO if you ran rails g devise somethingnonstandard you would have the functions somethingnonstandard_logged_in? etc. etc.

Comment: It makes sense, however I think is a bug of Devise so, because when I set :user with :class_name to 'User::Account', Devise should generate all scope methods with "user". Ill try your alternative, thanks!

Comment: OK, I tried to replace all 'user' with 'account', then 'user_account', but nothing work, because Im usaing namespace like 'User::Account', so what can I do? =/

Comment: What did you name your user model?

Comment: My model is 'User::Account'. The strange thing is that ALL runs well after reload on development environment.

Comment: Finally I solved this problem caused by 'clear_helpers' method!

Comment: Surprisingly you were right Devin. Under rails 4.2.3 and devise 3.4.1 it worked that way. Matching the method's name with the same model name used for the generator.